# Facebook share in drupal7 sharethis module picking wrong thumbnail image

Tags: social-network

I using ShareThis module in a drupal7 website for a certain content type say 'news'. When a user hits a Facebook share button, the title and links are fetched correctly but the thumbnail image it chooses is wrong.  I want my fbshare to pick my news image as its thumbnail image. Pls help.

thanks.

Update: i got it worked using MPD's comment. i explicitly added og:image in my header. Below is my code. Hope it helps someone.

```
$element = array(
            '#tag' => 'meta',
            '#attributes' => array(
                 "property" => "og:image",
                 "content" => $imagePath,
                  ),
            );
drupal_add_html_head($element,'fb_share_image');
```

Comment: when you say you added the above code to your header, which file is that specifically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you test the page with the [Facebook Debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)?  Remember that Facebook caches page info, so changes don't appear immediately.  A side effect of the debugger is that it clears the cache when you test a URL, so changes get picked up.

If you wan to use a specific image, you need to be sure it explicitly has an `og:image` element in the header.  I am pretty sure this is something that the [Meta Tags](http://drupal.org/project/metatag) module can do this for you.

Comment: thanks mpd for the Meta Tags link. it did add open graph meta tags for the title, and summary of the node, but not for the image. I think like you said i have to explicitly add og:image element in the header.